# CakePHP3 Many to Many relations

Tags: php, cakephp, many-to-many, cakephp-3.0

i am trying to save a form which has many to many relation in CakePHP3 but I can't render the form properly. (user HABTM tags)

In my controller i set the object that i want to edit:

```
$user = $this->Users->get($id, [
    'contain' => ['Tags']
]);
$this->set(compact('user'));
```

In the view I have:

```
$options = [
    '1' => 'Tag 1',
    '2' => 'Tag 2'
];
echo $this->Form->select('tags', $options, [
    'multiple' => 'checkbox'
]);
```

My problem is on the load the selected tags are not checked, how I can solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such a `belongsToMany` association you should make use of the `_ids` key in the fieldname, that way the form helper can magically pick up the values and check your boxes.

```
$this->Form->select('tags._ids',  /* ... */);
```

See

- **[Cookbook > Saving BelongsToMany Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-belongstomany-associations)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Creating Inputs for Associated Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#associated-form-inputs)**

for some info.

Also you should retrieve the list of tags from your table instead of defining them manually in the view

**controller**

```
// ...
$tags = $this->Users->Tags->find('list');
$this->set(compact('user', 'tags'));
```

**view**

```
echo $this->Form->select('tags._ids', $tags, [
    'multiple' => 'checkbox'
]);
```

See also **[Cookbook > Finding Key/Value Pairs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#finding-key-value-pairs)**